# Add custom link to pullrequest page in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I need add static link to all pullrequest pages in Bitbucket. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to include contributor guidelines, Bitbucket Cloud and Server both support. Details for each below.

If not, I'm curious what this link is intended for, but whatever it is there are extension points in Bitbucket Server that would allow you to do it with an add-on.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-a-contributions-guidelines-file-938025885.html

https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/01/26/pull-request-guidelines-for-bitbucket-cloud/